# ClassNotFoundException from Java Applet being served from IIS 7.5 under HTTPS

Tags: java, ssl, https, applet, iis-7.5

I'm having an issue trying to run a Java Applet from a .net aspx page being served from IIS 7.5.  If I use HTTP everything runs fine but if I try to use HTTPS I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on the class I have written for the applet.  If I try to hit the jar directly using HTTPS I am able to download it fine and the class file is within the jar file.  I'm using the follow javascript to try and run the applet:

```
$(function () {
    var applet = "<APPLET code=\"JavaApplet\"";
    applet += "archive=\"JavaApplet.jar\"";
    applet += "width=200 height=200 VIEWASTEXT>";
    applet += "</APPLET>";

    document.write(applet);
});
```

I have also tried loading it from an  tag and using JNLP with the same results.  Does anybody have any ideas on why this might be happening?  I can provide more information on my set up if needed.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have also tried using deployJava.js with the following javascript with the same results:

```
$(function () {
    var attributes = { code: 'JavaApplet',
        archive: 'JavaApplet.jar',
        width: 200, height: 200
    };
    var parameters = { };
    var version = '1.6';
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
});
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have edited my post with my attempt to use deployJava.js, which ended with the same results.  I'm not sure what the `VIEWASTEXT` is supposed to do actually... that is left over from before my time on this project, so it can probably be removed.  And yes, the applet should be embedded in a web page.

Comment: Ha, no worries, just a little miscommunication.  Again, I am very appreciative of any ideas you may have :)

Comment: Touche.  Unfortunately just a typo in this post, and not in the actual code.

Comment: I am using Chrome currently, so I do have the Chrome dev tools console.  It is not showing me any JS errors though.

Comment: Hint duly noted :)  Hmm... I have seen other applets run, but have not tried any others while using SSL.  I just tried this same code in FF and get the same error I see in Chrome though.

Comment: Hmm... I think I may have found something.  I believe this was happening because of the SSL cert I was using locally.  It was just a dev cert.  I've tried this applet from a test page on our production server which has a valid cert and it seems to work.  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this was happening due to how my testing environment was set up.  I was using a dev cert for the pages SSL.  After testing this applet from a test page on our production server, which is set up with a valid cert, everything looks to be working as expected using SSL.